# Publication Icons: Content vs Web

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, content-manager

Is there a way to change out icons per publication, lets say for Content vs Web?

Reason being, Content Authors could easily recognize the difference from a Content Publication and Web Publication at a glance.

I can change out the ***all*** publication icons here:

*Drive:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Themes\Carbon2\Images\Icons\Publication.(size).png*

Referencing the `id` of the publication types located here:

*Drive\Tridion\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config*

```
<publicationTypes>
  <!-- 
  Constraints: 
      1) id and name attribute is unique. 
      2) id > 1024. Numbers below 1024 are reserved.
      3) titleResource is optional. if titleResource is not provided then the value specified in name will be used as PublicationType.Title
  -->
  <add id="1" name="Content" titleResource="lblContentPublicationType" />
  <add id="2" name="Web" titleResource="lblWebPublicationType" />
  <add id="4" name="Mobile" titleResource="lblMobilePublicationType" />
</publicationTypes>
```

and adding a standard UI Extension (Editor) with the following configuration:

*Drive:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\CME.config*

```
<ext:editorextensions>
    <ext:editorextension target="CME">
  <ext:editurls />
        <ext:listdefinitions />
        <ext:itemicons>
            <icon match="^T1L[01]P[01]S1$" path="${theme}Images/Icons/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
            <icon match="^T1L[01]P[01]S2$" path="${theme}Images/Icons2/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
        </ext:itemicons>
    </ext:editorextension>
</ext:editorextensions>
```

and refresh the TCM, it throws an an error:

> Loading configuration file 
>   "Drive:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\CME.config"
>   failed: The element 'editorextension' in namespace
>   'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions' has incomplete
>   content. List of possible elements expected: 'taskbars' in namespace
>   'http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions'.

Both links go to **404 Error page**: http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remember Publication icons ever being different depending on type, but I did once create a UI extension that changed the icon of certain Publications (we made them pink cloud icons ;o), so that certainly is possible.

I think the icon based on a Publication Type was pretty simple, using a standard UI Extension (Editor), with the following configuration:

```xml
<extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:editorextension target="CME">
            <ext:editurls />
            <ext:listdefinitions />
            <ext:itemicons>
                <icon match="^T1L[01]P[01]S5$" path="${theme}Images/Icons/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
            </ext:itemicons>
            ....
```

And then I had the following icons created:

- T1L0P0S5.16x16.gray.png
- T1L0P0S5.16x16.png
- T1L0P0S5.24x24.png
- T1L0P0S5.32x32.png
- T1L0P0S5.48x48.png
- T1L0P1S5.16x16.png
- T1L0P1S5.24x24.png
- T1L0P1S5.32x32.png
- T1L0P1S5.48x48.png
- T1L1P0S5.16x16.png
- T1L1P0S5.24x24.png
- T1L1P0S5.32x32.png
- T1L1P0S5.48x48.png
- T1L1P1S5.16x16.png
- T1L1P1S5.24x24.png
- T1L1P1S5.32x32.png
- T1L1P1S5.48x48.png

Note the `S5` in my icon names and in the match of the configuration. We had created an additional Publication Type in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config` with id 5.

I think if you match `S1` and `S2` and create separate icons for that, you might be there with a simple UI (Editor) Extension.

Comment: Ok. I may have been mistaken with the icons in earlier versions. I appreciate the code sample, if possible.

Comment: I think it was in Tridion 2009. With the full re-build of the UI in 2011 this might have been "lost in the requirements"